# Cannot install "mysql2" getting error " Could not create makefile.."

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Beginner here, would really appreciate dome help!

I am trying to install ruby gem mysql2 but i am not able to and i am having a hard time telling exactly what error i am getting. I am using ruby version 2.1.5p273 and Rails version 4.0.0. I have tried moving libmysql.dll from \mysql to ruby \bin but that didn't work. Here is the command prompt messages.

```
C:\Users\Machine>gem install mysql2
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141210-6160-jqm1vd.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2
-0.3.17 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found a solution through some google fu at http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/questions/5857-cannot-install-mysql2-gem. It was in a comment a little ways down. I needed to extract mysql-connector-c-zip to my root drive and point to it in the command prompt.